# Securing roxyfilemanager in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, security, tinymce

I'm trying to build a website for myself. It has front and back end.

In the back end I have TinyMCE and I installed the standalone [roxyfileman file manger](http://www.roxyfileman.com/) and have it working perfect with my codeigniter site, but there's a catch.

I have my back end password protected via codeigniter sessions using a database
(I don't use password protected directories). I see that roxyfileman is accessible directly via browser if a user knows here to look, and a hacker could delete all pictures via file manager.

Example:
`sitename/js/fileman/index.html`

How can I secure the filemanager with codeigniter or any other way that will forbid direct access to the page?

In my case sessions are saved in database.
I gess I must figure out a way to connect the standalone filemanager to codeigniter and database and validate if a valid user is executing the filemanager.

Please advise on how to achieve this.

---

**Solution for me:**
Eventually I managed to find a great contribution from a developer.

Thanks to him I sorted my issue out.

Solution found here:

https://github.com/codinghamster/coreigniter

Comment: http://www.roxyfileman.com/security

Comment: Thanks. 

Perhasps I should have mentioned that I did read that page.

For any of you that know codeigniter I'm sure you will agree that the suggested solution:
"if($_SESSION['is_admin_logged'] !== true)exit;"

will not work.

Thanks

Comment: You said "standalone" so I guess that's to say it's not working "with" but "alongside" CodeIgniter. Why not do the same thing CodeIgniter does? Check the db manually.